# What would be a good open source lightweight c library with basic utility functionality to use in an embedded system

Tags: c, embedded

I'm thinking of something like [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/), but possibly a slim version with a minimal foot print.  It would need basic utilities such as linked lists, vectors and hash tables.  It should also have a minimal runtime footprint.

Comment: If your system really has stringent code size requirements, using general-purpose abstractions for data structures is probably not a good approach. Often an implementation closely coupled with the rest of the data structure and code can be a lot smaller and simpler.

Comment: Doesn't that really end up with a lot of duplicated logic if there are for instance a number of lists managed throughout the system?  I tend to think that closely coupled can help in the one off case, or even if the logic is required only a few time,s but at some point a general purpose implementation seems to be more appropriate doesn't it?  Otherwise you are re-implementing the same logic over and over again which would waste space and be prone to error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly a library, but a tested, optimized and documented piece of code: [`sys/queue.h`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sys/sys/queue.h?rev=1.32;content-type=text%2Fx-cvsweb-markup) on *BSD and Linux systems has macros for various kinds of intrusive linked lists and queues.

Comment: Looking it over I think that would work nicely for my purposes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[uthash](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/) is a nice hash table library (made entirely of macros), it also comes with a linked list, dynamic string and dynamic array macros.

I also highly recommend `sys/queue.h` (suggested by larsmans) for simple and well tested linked lists.