# C data structure library

Tags: c, data-structures

I want to use a stack in C, anybody recommend a library?

For example for a hash table I used UThash.

Thanks!

Comment: `sys/queue.h` has them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951020/what-would-be-a-good-open-source-lightweight-c-library-with-basic-utility-functio/3953575#3953575

Comment: `Closed as non constructive`?  I don't see how this question will lead to debate or discussion. It just happens that two of the answers are out of topic.Maybe a duplicate, but definitely constructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a similar question:

[Are there any open source C libraries with common data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668501/are-there-any-open-source-c-libraries-with-common-data-structures)

And here is CCAN, C's equivalent to CPAN:

http://ccan.ozlabs.org/

Answer (score 16):

Stack implementation fits in single sheet of paper.

That's simplest stack example

```
int stack[1000];

int *sp;

#define push(sp, n) (*((sp)++) = (n))
#define pop(sp) (*--(sp))
...
{
    sp = stack; /* initialize */

    push(sp, 10);
    x = pop(sp);
}
```

Answer (score -10):

If you can fudge it a bit and use C++, [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) is a really great library with a lot of basic data structures.

Comment: If C++ is acceptable, then Qt is not necessary. Stacks are in the C++ standard library.

Comment: found one from previous question, thanks!

Comment: Lars, I'd still use Qt for all of the other primitives it provides.  I find the C++ Standard Libraries woefully inadequate, but maybe that's my own personal preference.

Comment: @kidjan If you find the STL inadequate, you are in all likelyhood vastly overthinking your data structures and settling for subpar perfomance guarantees from QT. Use the STL at all opportunities.